# Select from same column under different conditons

Tags: sql-server, join

I need to join these two tables. I need to select occurrences where:

```
ex_head of_family_active = 1 AND tax_year = 2017
```

and also:

```
ex_head of_family_active = 0 AND tax_year = 2016
```

The first time I tried to join these two tables I got the warehouse data 
`dbo.tb_master_ascend AND warehouse_data.dbo.tb_master_ascend` in the from clause have the same exposed names. As the query now shown below, I get a syntax error on the "where". What am I doing wrong? Thank you

```
use [warehouse_data]

select
    parcel_number as Account,
    pact_code as type,
    owner_name as Owner,
    case 
       when ex_head_of_family_active >= 1 
          then 'X'
          else ''
    end 'Head_Of_Fam'
from 
    warehouse_data.dbo.tb_master_ascend
inner join 
    warehouse_data.dbo.tb_master_ascend on parcel_number = parcel_number
where 
    warehouse_data.dbo.tb_master_ascend.tax_year = '2016'
    and ex_head_of_family_active = 0   
where 
    warehouse_data.dbo.tb_master_ascend.t2.tax_year = '2017'
    and ex_head_of_family_active >= 1
    and (eff_from_date <= getdate())
    and (eff_to_date is null or eff_to_date >= getdate())
```

@marc_s I changed the where statements and updated my code however the filter is not working now:

```
use [warehouse_data]

    select 
    wh2.parcel_number as Account
    ,wh2.pact_code as Class_Type
    ,wh2.owner_name as Owner_Name 

    ,case when wh2.ex_head_of_family_active >= 1 then 'X'
         else ''
    end  'Head_Of_Fam_2017'

    from warehouse_data.dbo.tb_master_ascend as WH2
          left join warehouse_data.dbo.tb_master_ascend as WH1 on ((WH2.parcel_number = wh1.parcel_number)
          and (WH1.tax_year = '2016')
          and (WH1.ex_head_of_family_active is null))
    where WH2.tax_year = '2017'
            and wh2.ex_head_of_family_active >= 1       
            and (wh2.eff_from_date <= getdate())
            and (wh2.eff_to_date is null or wh2.eff_to_date >= getdate())
```

Comment: The syntax error is that you **cannot** have **two** `WHERE` clauses in a T-SQL statement

Comment: I am using MSSQL though. I should be able to use two where correct?

Comment: ***NO*** - you ***CANNOT*** have two  `WHERE` clauses in a T-SQL statement. You *can* however combine conditions using `AND` and `OR` - but there can **only be ONE** `WHERE` clause

Comment: @marc_s I changed the code to include the conditions to the join and only have One Where statement. Now the conditions for WH1 are not working once I removed them from from the where statement? They were there under the where statement using "and"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a CTE to get all your parcels that meet your 2016 rules.

Then join that against your 2017 rules on parcel ID.

I'm summarizing:

```
with cte as
(
select parcelID
from
where [2016 rules]
group by parcelID --If this isn't unique you will cartisian your results
)

select columns
from table
join cte on table.parcelid=cte.parcelID
where [2017 rules]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. What are the limitations using CTE?

Comment: @Tommy -- CTEs are essentially a subquery. Where it says cte in the bottom query you could essentially replace it with the select statement. It my preference to separate them out for neatness of the query. If my answer solved your problem can you mark it as an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you yes it did. As you can see from my edit above I went the select statement route. Was advised that this was a better route which is why I asked the limitations. I too preferred the CTE route as it seemed to illustrate my thought process better for this particular query. I am a novice for MSSQL so this was extreamly helpful.